# How do I make Sublime Text recognize my .sublime-syntax file

Tags: sublimetext3

Using PackageDev I created a myLanguage.sublime-syntax File, as it's documented everywhere, e.g. in https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/syntax.html. 
I saved it in .../Packages/User. But I can't see the new syntax in View->Syntax. There must be a step missing!?

Comment: Sublime just automatically loads syntax files without any extra steps, so all else being equal it should Just Work. If it doesn't, I would check the Sublime console to see what it says. A message should be printed every time you save the file; either an error, or something that tells you that it's generating a summary (i.e. compiling the syntax).

Comment: Thank you, the capitalization of the filename and the "name" field value were not matching.